# Twenty Twelve Calender Widget <a title="">post titles</a> creating disturbance

Tags: css, archives, calendar

In my modified Twenty Twelve theme, when I'm hovering onto the calender widget's date, there is a acronym-like balloon showing that date's post titles. Thing really is an anchor title:

```
<td>
   <a href="http://www.example.com/2013/01/23/" title="post title 1<br/>post title 2<br/>">23</a>
</td>
```

So when I'm hovering onto date 23, it's echoing like an acronym:

```
23
---------------
 post title 1
 post title 2
---------------
```

Problem is: My client doesn't want this.

If I can modify the default calendar widget, then I can delete the anchor title, and it will solve the problem. But I can't edit the default calendar widget.

- **QUESTION 1:** HOW TO EDIT WORDPRESS DEFAULT CALENDAR WIDGET?

Otherwise, I can make CSS for the specific title like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag). I did this like:

```
a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  display: none;
}
```

and/or

```
a[title]:hover:after {
      content: attr(title);
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

But failed. So, alternatively, the second question can be:

- **QUESTION 2:** HOW TO HIDE THE ANCHOR TITLE USING CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Third choice:  I suggest using jQuery to handle this.  `<script>$('a[title]').attr('title', '');</script>` will remove all anchor titles on the page.  You could put that in the page template or  build a widget that echos it.

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. Not disabling anchor title's from the widget. I tried it using before `wp_head()` once and then tried after `wp_head()` - not working. :(